# Drop down does not show the option selected in codeigniter

Tags: html, codeigniter

I used a drop down button to select an option from the given options. But when I selected an option it does not display that in the box. And I it gives chance only once to select an option. For the drop down I retrieve data from the database. 
This is the view code (Its inside Assign_Inquiries)

```
<select id = "counsellorname" name="counsellornamename" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle">
<option value = "0"> Select Category Name</option>                             
<?php

foreach($result as $row){
  echo "<option value = ".$row['email'].">".$row['fname']." ".$row['lname']."</option>";
}

?>
</select>
```

Its really great if someone can help me. Thanks inadvance

This is the controller code

```
<?php
class Assign_Inquiries_Controller extends CI_Controller{
    function index(){
        $this->load->model('Assign_Inquiries_Model');
        $data['result'] = $this->Assign_Inquiries_Model->index();
        //print_r($data);

        $this->load->view('Assign_Inquiries',$data);
    }
}



?>
```

This is the model code

```
<?php
class Assign_Inquiries_Model extends CI_Model{
    function index(){
        $this->db->select('first_name,last_name,email');
        $where = "status =3";
        $this->db->where($where);
        $query = $this->db->get('user');
        foreach ($query -> result() as $row) {
            $data[] = array(
                'fname' => $row->first_name,
                'lname' => $row->last_name,
                'email' => $row->email
                );
        }
        return $data;
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: could you post your controller code form where `$result` is passed to views?

Comment: @U Isiru i think this is code inside your view.

Comment: I have attached the controller code above

Comment: are you returning data on array fromat? from model..if not also post your model's code.

Comment: I have also attached the model code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your model code as below: use `result_array()` which returns the result in array format.

```
function index(){
        $this->db->select('first_name,last_name,email');
        $this->db->where('status',3);
        $query = $this->db->get('user');
        return $query ->result_array();

    }
```

In view you loop must be like this....

```
foreach($result as $row){
  echo "<option value = ".$row['email'].">".$row['first_name']." ".$row['last_name']."</option>";
}
```

Comment: When I chaned the model as above now it does not display the values in the drop down. Earlier it displayed but the problem was that I couldn't select an option. soo do you have any alternative method for this???

Comment: I changed the model and the view.It displayed the data from the database but when I select an option it does not change the value currently in the drop down box and changed to the selected one. And after I select the option the a  '#' mark is added after the url and cannot click the drop down button(seems like it is disbaled) .Is this error occured because of CI cuz the same code worked without the CI framework?????. Its really great if you can help me to solve the problem